# WPF user control gets data from web service or dll

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, class-library

I have a WPF user control which displays a piece of data on the screen.

I would like to use the same WPF front end but have the data come from two possible alternate sources:

1. A linked class library or
2. A WCF service

The rationale is that I want to create two versions of my software one for sale and the other for trial. Rather than run the risk of creating a fully-contained application which is protected by some time-limit and have someone hack it, I'd prefer to give a client-server version of the software where I can limit the availability from the back-end.

For example, say the user control displays the day of the week and I get the day of the week from a method GetDayOfWeek(DateTime dateTime). I want to be able to either call that method from a linked class library or from a WCF service. (The decision can be based on a configuration parameter or even by automatically detecting the presence of the linked library).

Any ideas?

Comment: 1 - This is not a question. 2 - What you're looking for is called SaaS (software as a Service) where the software vendor hosts the server side of the software himself. 3 - WPF Encourages the separation between Presentation and Functionality/Business Logic with the use of `MVVM`, therefore you must develop the application in such a way that the WPF UI doesn't really "care" where the data is coming from.

Comment: Perhaps I was not sufficiently clear with my question. I am familiar with the concept of SaaS. What I am looking for is a solution which can use the same front-end WPF XAML with either a WCF back-end (SaaS) or a standalone back-end. How do I construct the code so that it will compile even if the standalone back-end is not linked to it and it can choose at run-time whether to load and link the standalone back-end or use the WCF service?